# .append image src as text to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

so I'm trying to append image src to a div when you click on it...so far I've written it like this and it doesn't seem to work, no error reports, no idea what's going on. The image is of a class .card (there's 15 of them), and I want to append to the div only if the border is gray, you click once to select the card (changing the border) and then click again to paste the selected card onto the div...the div is called .picks. I just want to display the image src as text on my page. thanks for the help

```
$(".card").click(function() {
console.log("click");
if($(this).css('border')==="4px solid gray") {
    var cardname = $(this).attr('src');
    $(".picks").append(cardname);
    if(pick<15) {
        pick++;
    }
    else {
        booster++;
        pick=1;
    }
}
else {
    $(this).css('border', '4px solid gray');
}
});
```

Comment: those are just some variables used in other parts of the program. Basically pick = 1, booster = 1.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: Or can you post the HTML?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1o7tgs5j/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you rely on result of `css("border")` while it's not what you expect: e.g. Chrome will retrieve border styles as `"4px solid rgb(128, 128, 128)"`.

Instead set CSS class `selected` and check if the card has this class or not:

```
$(".card").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        var cardname = $(this).attr('src');
        $(".picks").append(cardname);
        if (pick < 15) {
            pick++;
        } else {
            booster++;
            pick = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/1o7tgs5j/13/

In general as the rule of thumb, avoid using `$.fn.css` method for styling, not only this is very obtrusive but also error prone approach. In most cases usage of addClass/removeClass brings much more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
if($(this).css('border')==="4px solid rgb(128, 128, 128)") 
{
  ....
}
```

**But i will suggest you to do it this way...**

```
$(".card").click(function () {
    console.log("click");
    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        var cardname = $(this).attr('src');
        $(".picks").append(cardname);
        if (pick < 15) {
            pick++;
        } else {
            booster++;
            pick = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $(this).css('border', '4px solid gray').addClass("clicked");
    }
});
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1o7tgs5j/12/)**

Comment: althought this anwser is correct, dfsq posted the correct anwser a bit before you, so I'm going to accept his version. thanks for the help